# Testing a broadcast from a service, called from a controller

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

In my Angular controller I make a call to a service to attach multiple events to a grid. For example, I attach an `onXLE` event to the grid like so:

```
gridService.attachEvent("visibilityGrid", "onXLE", function () {
        $rootScope.$broadcast("loader_hide");
    });
```

but I'm also attaching (using the same same function from the service) other events like `onCheck` and `onDynXLS`. The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to check if the `$broadcasts` are firing. I tried the usual approach:

```
it( 'should attach the onXLE event to the grid',function() {
   spyOn( gridService,'attachEvent' );
   spyOn( $rootScope,'$broadcast' );

   // First test passes
   expect( gridService.attachEvent ).toBeDefined();   

   // This fails...
   expect( $rootScope.$broadcast ).toHaveBeenCalledWith( 'loader_hide' );
```

});

It returns this error:

```
Expected spy $broadcast to have been called with [ 'loader_hide' ] but it was never called.
```

What am I missing to make this test work?

**UPDATE**

The call to `$locationChangeStart` occurs here:

```
// For any route changes, check if roles have already been obtained, if not, then retrieve them.
    $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, newUrl, oldUrl){

        messageService.clearAllMessages("messageContainer");

        if(!authService.isInitialized()) {

            if(authService.isDevMode()){

                dataService.getRoles(AUTH_APPLICATION_ID, function(response){
                    $scope.root.initAuthorization(response);
                });

            } else {

                dataService.retrieveSMHeaders()
                    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                        authService.setEmployeeId(headers('EMPLOYEE_ID'));
                        authService.setEmployeeName(headers('USER_NAME'));
                        authService.setEmployeeSurname(headers('USER_SURNAME'));

                        // Set the Headers required to access Common Services.
                        $http.defaults.headers.common.SERVICES_ID = AUTH_SERVICES;

                        dataService.getRoles(AUTH_APPLICATION_ID, 
                            function(response){
                                $scope.root.initAuthorization(response);
                            },
                            function(status){
                                event.preventDefault();
                                $location.url("/unauthorized");
                            }
                        );

                    });
            }
        }

        authService.getAuthPromise().then(function(){

            var isAuthorized = false;
            var userRoles = $route.current.$$route.roles;
            if(userRoles){
                var userRoleArray = userRoles.split(',');
                for (x=0; x<userRoleArray.length; x++){
                    if(authService.hasRole(userRoleArray[x])){
                        isAuthorized = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                isAuthorized = true;
            }

            if (!isAuthorized) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $location.url("/unauthorized");
            }
        });
    });
```

The point of this above is to determine if the user has the correct role to carry out the action - if not it obtains them

Answer (score 2):

Events broadcast (and emit) within digest cycles and in your tests you will need to initiate that yourself by calling `$rootScope.$apply()`

```
it( 'should attach the onXLE event to the grid',function() {
   spyOn( gridService,'attachEvent' );
   spyOn( $rootScope,'$broadcast' );

   // First test passes
   expect( gridService.attachEvent ).toBeDefined();   

   // this is what you are missing
   $rootScope.$apply();

   // This fails...
   expect( $rootScope.$broadcast ).toHaveBeenCalledWith( 'loader_hide' );   
});
```

**Note:** This is also true when resolving promises.

Comment: Hello again Brocco - I'm away from the laptop with the code. I'm aware of what you're saying and I'm quite sure that I did do that but still received the same error - will confirm soon

Comment: I did try what you suggested but now I'm receiving the same error but it says that the actual calls were '$locationChangeStart' and '$locationChangeSuccess' - I'm believe that these should probably be mocked out in the same way that a $location is mocked out via injection - what do you think?

Comment: Are there any other specs/suites that are run before this one? I'm thinking that some other test is causing those other entries.

Comment: Yes there were 41 tests in this class for this one controller - i commented out all of them but still received the same error

Comment: I don't see anything with what you have here that would initiate either of those events. There has to be some other code in your tests that would be causing this.

Comment: I've searched through the entire project and $locationChangeStart is only called on one place and that's in a file called app-controllers. In this file there is a controller called 'ApprootController' that makes the call - I've updated my question to include that call

Comment: `$locationChangeStart` is an event that is broadcast from within the `ngRoute` module, do you have any tests that would be changing the route? maybe via $location.path or $location.url? By spying on $broadcast you are listening for ALL events, not just the one you are looking for.

Comment: I've removed every test outside of this one so that karma only runs this one test - I tinkered with the test and its giving me the error 'Cannot read property of defaultPrevented' of undefined

Comment: Ignore the above - that occurs when you don't call .andCallThrough() on the broadcast mock - do you think this occurs simply because the test has uncovered a bug in that the event doesn't actually broadcast?

Comment: So, kids, be sure to do `spyOn( $rootScope,'$broadcast' ).and.callThrough();` instead of just `spyOn( $rootScope,'$broadcast' )`